Is there a way to make sure your std::atexit function works when stopping the Xcode debugger?
Found that when you halt your C++ program from Xcode using "Stop Debugging", your atexit function gets skipped
Any way to do this, especially when debugging an iOS app?

The atexit handler is called "on normal program termination". Terminating a process in the debugger is not considered normal. What critical functionality are you implementing in atexit that makes you seek such unorthodox behavior as executing further instructions while force-terminating a process?

@paddy closing the log file handle!

Maybe [edit] and show some code to illustrate what kind of handle this is. Generally, any resources acquired by a process are automatically released back to the operating system when it tears down the process.

@bobobobo All file handles are closed automatically when the program terminates (for whatever reason). This is true at least for POSIX, and probably for Windows, too.

@bitmask If a FILE* isn't fclosed, then it may not have put out some data to the file yet. I have a workaround of calling fflush each time I write to the log file though

@bobobobo Maybe make the logfile unbuffered. Especially if there are errors in the program, you might loose the most crucial messages close before program termination -- not just during debugging but also in any other situation.

You mean like this?
